# Team Foundation Build Service building in wrong location - VS2008 Team System

Tags: tfsbuild

This concerns how I can define where a TFS build agent pulls the sourcecode to before/when doing a build.

We are rebuilding our obsolete and slow WinXP build server on a much faster new Win7x64 Pro server. All the software has been installed, and existing build definitions successfully start, using the new build agent definition. The only visible differences between the old and new build agents are the agent name and the target server name: builds are defined to be dropped into the same share on each server (\\servername\builds), and each build agent defines the build location as $(Temp)\$(BuildDefinitionPath). We have taken care to recreate exactly the same build location folder structure on the new machine as on the old. Both build services run under the same account (\DevBuildServer), although generally the builds are run without logging in to Windows.

Howver there is a snag: using the same build definition the old build agent correctly gets the source code to the desired target location (d:\temp on the old server), but the new  build agent gets it all to the wrong drive and path on the new server.

From the logs:

Old build agent:
 Get TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://devserver2:8080/" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/3437" Force=True Overwrite=False PopulateOutput=False Preview=False Recursive=True Version="C6165" Workspace="DEVBUILDSERVER_25"
  Getting d:\Temp\Matrix5Branches\Matrix5313\Sources....etc

New build agent:
 Get TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://devserver2:8080/" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/3459" Force=True Overwrite=False PopulateOutput=False Preview=False Recursive=True Version="C6176" Workspace="DEVBUILDSERVER2_30"
  Getting C:\Users\DEVBUILDSERVER\AppData\Local\Temp\Matrix5Branches....etc

The problem is that on the new  server the target path is too long, so the build fails. Also we need to have the builds themselves on a separate drive so they are not backed  up. So on the new build server I need to set the target path for the source code to d:\temp. My question is: How/where is the location/path for the build target folder (ie where the build is done) set? I've tried creating a new build agent definition and a new build from scratch but I can't find anywhere that this is defined, but clearly it is, somewhere, because whoever built the old build server has managed it.

TIA - if I get this fixed today I can look forward to a relaxed weekend....

Comment: If you are using the same TFSBuild.proj files as on the old machine, those have a few machine/path names etc coded into them at the top.  You may want to take a look in there if you haven't already.

Comment: The only paths defined in the TFSBuild.proj file are commented as there for backwards compatibility with V1 (we are later than that). Syncing them does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in using $(Temp) in your [`Working Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399135%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#agent_properties_workdir) on the Build Agent Properties. This uses the TEMP environment variable which defaults to [%SystemDrive%\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) on Windows 7

There are two options:

1. Change the TEMP environment variable
2. Change the Working Directory setting on build agents

Comment: Thanks. I've tried (1) by changing the env variable for the service account (DevBuildServer) and alternatively (2) instead in the build agent definition, but in both cases it now fails with a path not found error:
TF215085: An error occurred while connecting to agent ...: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\d;\temp\tmp9ameu.tmp'Thanks. I've tried (1) by changing the env variable for the service account (DevBuildServer) and alternatively (2) instead in the build agent definition, but in both cases it now fails with a path not found error:

Comment: I ought to add that the env variable TEMP on the build server does not contain a ';'

Comment: Restarted Visual Studio on the machine launching the builds, and that cured the file path problem.